# Using nonce in custom Wordpress API end-point

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

I'm trying to write an plugin that allows a Wordpress authenticated user to access Firebase. I'd like a Javascript app that is delivered from Firebase hosting to make an API request to Wordpress and get back a signed JWT.

Since I want to use the authenticated user, I figure I'll need to send a nonce with the API request. In order to test that I've got the following code Plugin code:

```
function my_awesome_func($data) {
  $uid = $data['id'];
  // var_dump($data);  
  var_dump(wp_create_nonce( 'wp_rest' ));
  var_dump(get_current_user_id());
  return $uid;
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'telomere/firebase_jwt/v1', '/user/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );
```

The idea being - the first time I hit the end-point it returns the nonce. I'll then append it to the URL and try again, hopefully getting the current user details the second time around.
`http://localhost/wp-json/telomere/firebase_jwt/v1/user/1234?_wpnonce=<nonce>`

All I get back is
`{"code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce","message":"Cookie nonce is invalid","data":{"status":403}}`

How do I fix this code so that it provides and accepts a nonce?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was my misunderstanding of how a nonce was created (despite the docs being excellent).

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_create_nonce/ states that it uses the user's UID in the generation of the nonce, but when I first called the custom API end-point the user was presenting as unauthenticated. The nonce then created didn't verify.

Instead, I copied the Hello Dolly code and output an authenticated nonce on the admin page and then used that in my test API call.

FWIW, it looks like this

```php
function my_awesome_func($data) {
  $uid = $data['id'];
  return $uid;
}


add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
  register_rest_route( 'telomere/firebase_jwt/v1', '/user/(?P<id>\d+)', array(
    'methods' => 'GET',
    'callback' => 'my_awesome_func',
  ) );
} );


function output_nonce() {
  $nonce = wp_create_nonce('wp_rest');
    printf('nonce %s', $nonce);
}


add_action( 'admin_notices', 'output_nonce' );
```

Comment: More on the subject: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Answer (score 0):

You have used wp_create_nonce in server response area - which is wrong. That is a place for wp_verify_nonce.
You need to create wp_create_nonce at  a client side.

For example:

```
jQuery.ajax( {
        url: "YOUR_API_URL?api_nonce=<?php echo wp_create_nonce("wp-rest"); ?>",
        method: 'GET'
    } ).done( function ( response ) {
});
```

And then, inside callback function you can verify it

```
function my_awesome_func($data) {
  var_dump(wp_verify_nonce( $_GET["api_nonce"], 'wp-rest' ) );
  return $uid;
}
```

Or better to use official guide for API auth: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for this, but unfortunately I don't think that will help. I need the API request to be authenticated by the accompanying WP cookie when initiated from a remote server. The remote service cannot authenticate, it needs a user to have previously done that on the WP site.

Comment: The given link my answer shows exactly that way - auth via existing website cookie.

Comment: Yes, but only when Wordpress is rendering the page that will call the API. In my circumstance Wordpress is not, it is a SPA served from static hosting on a different domain. I've been stepping through the underlying Wordpress code and I think I see where the problem is. If I fix it, I'll post the issue. I'm being dumb is the most likely answer.